# Is Django For A Suitable For A Procedure Orientad Programming Lover?

Tags: python, django, oop

I have lack of knowledge on Python advanced OOP. Even though I know basic OOP. How to create a class, role of self, craft objects, basic understanding of init and super function etc. I just wanted to know is it good enough to learn Django? Or Django is like PyQt. I need lots of knowledge on advanced OOP? I am a C programmer mainly so I love to play with functions for developing software. Should I go for Django or I need to drive taxi?

Comment: Sorry this question is off-topic as it's 1. too broad 2. opinion-based. It's impossible to answer here in a succinct way as only you know the best way to learn and the topic is so broad that you will never stop learning

Comment: @EdChum So StackOverFlow is for what? To see old answers? Everytime I ask a question I get a down vote and someone says it is off topic, opinion based blah blah blah. Ridiculous!!!

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. What exactly are you asking, whether it's worth learning django? Then yes, the answer will vary from person to person

Comment: Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if not done already and in particular what is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: "*So StackOverFlow is for what?*" For asking a question to which someone can provide a definitive answer. Not their opinion. I think Django is *very unsuitable*, whereas Bob over there thinks it's *absolutely perfect* and Sally thinks it's *ok but there are better ones*, and Mary thinks it's *sometimes ok, not always, in X scenario it is, in Y it is not*, John thinks *you should use this other software instead*, and Percy thinks *you should use something else different to Django and John's suggestion* - etc, etc.

Comment: The question is clear. Perhaps you guys read it thoroughly. I think most of you became harsh on me to show off yourself and due to your arrogance. Also some can't restrict themself from miss use of their reputation for giving down votes. Come on guys. Otherwise soon you will see there is no respect left for software engineers.

Comment: It's not unclear, it's too broad for this site and will attract opinion based answers, rather than clear factual answers. When you have "should I choose X or Y software" and "Is X software suitable" it is a bit broad and brings opinions. See my previous comment for an example of what usually happens. We're not being unkind to you, it is just how the site works, and it works well for keeping it this way. If you want opinions and have a discussion about options, you need a forum really, not a Q&A site.

Comment: @James don't ruin the field any more. Nowadays people don't respect computer programmers because of this kind of arrogance and harsh behavior. What you earn from me just talking like foolish again and again. My question was clear "whether Django heavily depends on OOP or not"? As my OOP skill is not remarkable so I asked this question. My experience with PyQt wasn't comfortable so before diving in Django I asked to learn from experienced programmers. If you dont understand then stay away from my question. But you are stupidly arguing and trying to abuse me. Even with just 2k reputation!!!!

Comment: @cherry Your question has been put on hold by other users of the site, not myself. I was just trying to help you as a new user understand the way in which Stack is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django isn't particularly object-orientated. The main place where you need to use classes is in defining and querying models;  if you understand the basics of defining a class and creating an instance of it, you'll probably have enough to get started with.

All the rest of the functionality - eg writing views and templates - can be done in a fairly procedural way.

Comment: I think the reason why few people respect programmers is still here is some people like you. I have found stack over flow members very harsh to newbies. Don't know why? If this kind of arrogance they show in their everyday life soon all will start heating programmers. However you made me happy. Yes I know those nifty stuffs. I was a bit afraid because I had some experience with PyQt. PyQt is full of classes and OOP. Which was difficult for me. So before diving in Django I need to be ensured whether I am wasting my time or not. Many thanks with respect from me. :)

Comment: "*I have found stack over flow members very harsh to newbies*" and I find many newbies harsh to Stack Overflow members who know how the site works. We try to advise, but the way the site works doesn't fit in with their requirements and they just want their answer, so they don't want to know about it and won't take advice. This too could be argued as "arrogance" as you used. Regardless, factually this "is" a *Q&A site*, and Answers should not be subjective. This answer (no offence Daniel) is not an "Answer" we want here, it's a discussion point, advice at best, and this is not a forum :)

Comment: Personally, I don't see what's wrong with this question or my answer. OP was asking "Can you use Django without writing much OOP code", to which the answer - as I state - is yes. That's quite different from asking "Should I use Django", or "is it good to use OOP", which are definitely subjective. Still, others are free to disagree, and to downvote as they think fit.

Comment: @James Daniel has much more respect than you. I will tell my children to be a programmer like Daniel who understood the question and even though has more than 20K reputation still such a polite and a real gentleman. He again proved as wise as you are as broad as your mind is. On the other hand every answer is blended with some sort of opinion. Probably my English is bad so I wasnt able to express what I want to ask but being a native you can easily get the spirit. And again I will say this kind of arrogant attitude is ruining the field. Keep in mind that everybody was a beginner.

Comment: *Q* "Can you use Django without writing much OOP code"  *A* "yes", surely this is searchable info, and not really the sort of quality we want here? Your answer reads like a forum post, or summary on a wiki of how Django works, info which should be readily available in a basic guide/intro when first stepping into learning something. Again, no offence at all, I know you're just trying to help, but the site is not just for one user to get an answer, we're supposed to at least be trying to make the Q's and A's useful to others. And trying to avoid low quality localised questions.